# Bicubic Spline Interpolation

Tags: bicubic

I have reviewed the way Bicubic Interpolation work and know how to make the basic steps. However, the point im missing is that how i could find the value in between. The reference im picking on is this :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation. Say for example i need to find value of f(0.5, 0.5) . How to do so?

If the reference i get was wrong or not complete, i appreciate any addition information that would help me.Also i would appreciate some test case to help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically have points in a grid around the point you're interested in.

The first step is to perform interpolation on all the points in one dimension (often X) so you can get an interpolated value matching the X coordinate you're interested in.

The second step is to compute the value for all the rows at the X you want, and use that to interpolate along the second dimension. That will allow you to compute a value for the Y coordinate you want.

You don't necessarily need to compute all the rows, just as many as needed for your interpolation. For cubic splines, I think that's two above and two below, but check to be sure.